# How can I access the method of parent and grandparent in child class with same name but with different output

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I want to know how can I access the method of grandparent's in child class as a sequence in with I have written in void main(). I have been facing difficulty in accessing the methods in the sequence of the code. I cannot find anything to make it run smoothly.

```
import java.util.*;
class  first{
    void view(){
        System.out.println("I am in View");
    }
    void display(){
        System.out.println("I am in First's Display");
    }
}
class  second extends first{
    void show(){
        System.out.println("I am in Show");
    }
    void display(){
        System.out.println("I am in Second's Display");
    }
}
class  third extends second{
    void output(){
        System.out.println("I am in Output");
    }
    void display(){
        System.out.println("I am in Third's Display");
    }
}
class demo{
    public static void main(String s[]){
        third d = new third();
        d.view();
        d.display();
        d.show();
        d.display();
        d.output();
        d.display();        
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error that you're facing?

Comment: Try to use the `super()` operator as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)